# Angular 6 Router not detecting Url change with angularjs $location service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-hybrid

I have a hybrid angular application using Angular 6 and AngularJS 1.6.4. I have defined all the routes in Angular module and upgraded the AngularJS components using UpgradeComponent as stated in Upgrade Guide.

When I try to navigate from one AngularJS view to another AngularJS view using $location service, the url in browser window gets changed but the Angular Router doesn't detect the url change and same view remains loaded in UI.
I tried to subscribe to router events and Location service events, none are firing.

However when I click on other link, it navigates to that link. Also after moving to new link, when I click on the back button of browser, it navigates the application to the link which didn't work earlier.
Example:

1. Current Url is http://localhost/#/App/View1
2. Click on link to http://localhost/#/App/View2. Url is updated but View1 is still loaded in UI.
3. Click on link to http://localhost/#/App/View3. Url is updated and View3 is loaded.
4. Click on back button of the browser. Url is updated to View2 and View2 is loaded in UI.

If I use $window service of AngularJS instead of $location, everything works. It was working with Angular 4 before upgrading to Angular 6.
Please help in making it work using $location service.